# Main Webpage getting longer and longer as the contents in a div tag are reloaded after a specific time interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making a web page where I want to load the contents of a php file in a div tag. Say for example after every 5 seconds refresh the div contents and load a php to update itself on my main page without reloading my main page.

The problem I have is as the timer reloads the div contents my main web page is getting longer and longer vertically and slows the web page.

I am trying to load this way:
scripts used are php, jquery, html

```
function Load_external_content(){
  $('#chatsidebar').empty();
  $('#chatsidebar').load('chatcnew.php');
}

setInterval('Load_external_content()', 5000);
```

```html
<div class="chat-sidebar" id='chatsidebar'>
  <?php include("chatcnew.php"); ?>
</div>
```

The data from my chatcnew.php file is loading properly in my div but the scrolling occurs on my main page and I am not sure whats happening.

Comment: If you're building a chat system I'd strongly suggest you use web sockets. All polling does is DDOS your own server.

Answer (score 0):

try setTimeout instead because load html cost uncertain time.

```
function Load_external_content(){
   $('#chatsidebar').empty();
   //you can do optimizing: render chatcnew.php is not necessary if the data of the chatcnew.php not change 
   $('#chatsidebar').load('chatcnew.php',function(){
       setTimeout(Load_external_content,5000);
   });
}
Load_external_content();
```